# Returning a value of a column as null or empty when a value of other column in the same table is 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I am working on an SQL Query which has some joins which results certain number of rows and columns. I am trying to return the results in such a way that when a value in particular column of a row is 1 then some other value in the same row but different column should be returned as Empty value.

My SQL Query in SQL Server 2012 is as follows

```
select a.id,a. Date, c.companyname as 'Active Company', h.employee_fullname as ‘Client',j.displayname as 'Seller Employee', d.companyName as 'CounterParty Company',g.broker_fullname as 'Buyer Trader', a.transactiontype
from confirmations a with (nolock)
left join company c with (nolock) on c.company_id = a.activecompany
left join company d with (nolock) on d.company_id = a.counterCompany
left join bprod e with (nolock) on e.id = a.productID
left join btype f with (nolock) on  f.id = a.quantitytypeid
left join companybroker g with (nolock) on g.companybroker_id = a.counter
left join companybroker h with (nolock) on h.companybroker_id = a.active
left join users i with (nolock) on i.id = a.buyemp
left join users j with (nolock) on j.id = a.sellemp
Where JoinDate > '2011-06-04 00:00:00' 
and a.disabled = 0 
order by dealid
```

Above Query returns following results

```
Id Active Company Client Seller Employee CounterPartyCompany Buyer Trader Transaction Type
1  ABC             XYZ      PQR             CHEV                 John           0
2  ABC2            2XYZ    2PQR            2CHEV                 John11         0
3  3ABC            3XYZ     3PQR           3CHEV                 John12         1
4  3ABC            3XYZ     AAA              CCC                 John12         1
```

Everything looks fine but I am trying to return `CounterPartyCompany` as Empty when  `Transaction Type` is 1 which looks like following

```
 Id Active Company Client Seller Employee CounterPartyCompany Buyer Trader Transaction Type
    1  ABC             XYZ      PQR             CHEV                 John           0
    2  ABC2            2XYZ    2PQR            2CHEV                 John11         0
    3  3ABC            3XYZ     3PQR                                 John12         1
    4  3ABC            3XYZ     AAA                                  John12         1
```

May I know a better way to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfect use for case statement:

```
select a.id, a.Date, c.companyname as 'Active Company', 
h.employee_fullname as 'Client', j.displayname as 'Seller Employee', 
case when a.transactionType =1 then null
else d.companyName end as 'CounterPartyCompany',
g.broker_fullname as 'Buyer Trader', a.transactiontype
from confirmations a with (nolock)
left join company c with (nolock) on c.company_id = a.activecompany
left join company d with (nolock) on d.company_id = a.counterCompany
left join bprod e with (nolock) on e.id = a.productID
left join btype f with (nolock) on  f.id = a.quantitytypeid
left join companybroker g with (nolock) on g.companybroker_id = a.counter
left join companybroker h with (nolock) on h.companybroker_id = a.active
left join users i with (nolock) on i.id = a.buyemp
left join users j with (nolock) on j.id = a.sellemp
Where JoinDate > '2011-06-04 00:00:00' 
and a.disabled = 0 
order by dealid
```

This does assume that only 1 should be null/empty.  All other occurrences of transactionType will result in the d.companyName being displayed.